# run Tor relay only my overnight when not deducted from my data allowance

Tags: relays, windows

my ISP limits me to 10Gb per month. I do not want Tor using this.
However from midnight to 8 am the allowance is not affected so i could run a Tor relay.
Editing my Windows XP torrc file `C:\Documents and Settings\ianstx\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc` will start a relay but once 8 am arrives I will replace the `torrc` file with the `torrc.orig` file, but how can i stop the relay? do i need to [re]start a Tor browser or kill a process or service?

Comment: nps! Run it as a Windows service **From a separated non-admin user** and start and stop it in by-time manner. Need further instructions?

Comment: Running a relay just over night is not that useful. Please check this blog post: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay It takes several days until the relay is used. In your situation it might be better to run a bridge: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#RelayOrBridge